# Simulation of thin plastic

Tags: materials

Is it possible to simulate the properties of cellophane in blender? I am trying to understand how a cellophane tube will deform as it passes through a shaped apperture.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean "a cellophane tube": does the tube enter the aperture from its edge or from the top/bottom? what drives its movement? Anyway, you shouldn't use Blender to **understand** a physical process: Blender is not accurate enough and you don't have control over all its real-world parameters and approximations. You can use Blender to obtain a **visually convincing** animation representing a physical process.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to simulate the appearance of the material and the form to some degree while working with reference material like photographs. If you need it the other way around - to know how the reality will look from something you would do in Blender, unfortunately Blender is not designed for that. Tools in Blender are more aimed to achieving visuals, not correctly simulating reality according to measured properties of materials. You could experiment and compare simulations to what happens in reality so it might be possible for you to guess some things based on the simulations, but that might not be an easy task in Blender.

I have attempted to predict the behavior of fabrics before but it was with Marvelous Designer that has *way more* features than Blender when it comes to cloth simulation. From my experience it is always still guessing and you need a lot of experimentation before you can even start guessing the most basic things. I attempted to predict how a beanbag design would look:

[image]

You can see my closest prediction of how the design would look on the right and a photogrammetric reconstruction of the actual bean bag made on the left. The overall form seems to match, but if you look at the details it starts to differ quite a lot because of the limited resolution of the simulations. Keep in mind this is done in software that is a lot more advanced in simulations, so I would expect the results in Blender to be a lot more approximate. Either way this would require a lot of work and a lot of experimentation and in the end is mostly just guessing.